# what is purpose of default_datastore database in ckan? I want to user default_datastore db for dataset

Tags: datastore, ckan

ckan 2.2.1 + solr 3.6 + postgresql 9.1 + rhel 6.6

Hi.

In ckan installation guide, have to create two database (ckan_default, datastore_default)

I set datastore seting in configuration file then I create new dataset by ckan web interface.
But all datasets are stored in ckan_default database not datastore_default database.
The datastore_default database is empty. How to use datastore_default database for dataset?

This is snippet of my ini configuration files

```
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:PASS@localhost/ckan_default
ckan.datastore.write_url = postgresql://ckan_default:PASS@localhost/datastore_default
ckan.datastore.read_url = postgresql://datastore_default:PASS@localhost/datastore_default
ckan.datastore.default_fts_lang = english
ckan.datastore.default_fts_index_method = gist
ckan.site_url = http://ckan.inje.com
ckan.auth.anon_create_dataset = false
ckan.auth.create_unowned_dataset = false
ckan.auth.create_dataset_if_not_in_organization = false
ckan.auth.user_create_groups = false
ckan.auth.user_create_organizations = false
ckan.auth.user_delete_groups = true
ckan.auth.user_delete_organizations = true
ckan.auth.create_user_via_api = false
ckan.auth.create_user_via_web = true
ckan.auth.roles_that_cascade_to_sub_groups = admin
ckan.site_id = default
solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/core0
ckan.redis.url = redis://localhost:6379/0
ckan.plugins = datastore stats text_view image_view recline_view
ckan.views.default_views = image_view text_view recline_view
ofs.impl = pairtree
ofs.storage_dir = /var/lib/ckan
ckan.site_title = CKAN
ckan.site_logo = /base/images/ckan-logo.png
ckan.site_description =
ckan.favicon = /images/icons/ckan.ico
ckan.gravatar_default = identicon
ckan.preview.direct = png jpg gif
ckan.preview.loadable = html htm rdf+xml owl+xml xml n3 n-triples turtle plain atom csv tsv rss txt json
ckan.locale_default = en
ckan.locale_order = en pt_BR ja it cs_CZ ca es fr el sv sr sr@latin no sk fi ru de pl nl bg ko_KR hu sa sl lv
ckan.locales_offered =
ckan.locales_filtered_out = en_GB
ckan.feeds.authority_name =
ckan.feeds.date =
ckan.feeds.author_name =
ckan.feeds.author_link =
ckan.storage_path = /var/lib/ckan
ckan.max_resource_size = 10
ckan.max_image_size = 2
ckan.datapusher.url = http://127.0.0.1:8800/
email_to = you@yourdomain.com
error_email_from = paste@localhost
smtp.server = localhost
smtp.starttls = False
[loggers]
keys = root, ckan, ckanext
[handlers]
keys = console
[formatters]
keys = generic
[logger_root]
level = WARNING
handlers = console
[logger_ckan]
level = INFO
handlers = console
qualname = ckan
propagate = 0
[logger_ckanext]
level = DEBUG
handlers = console
qualname = ckanext
propagate = 0
[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic
[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
```

I want to use datastore_default db to store and read dataset in ckan web interface. 
Anyone have an idea for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `ckan_default` is for the dataset metadata (description records)
- `datastore_default` is where data can (optionally) be stored, linked to the metadata in `ckan_default`. This functionality is managed by the CKAN [Datastore extension](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html)

To put data into DataStore you would normally set-up DataPusher and then every time you add a dataset then it would be added to DataStore automatically.

Comment: as you can see my ini file. I set datastore in ckan.plugin section. But I could not able to see any resource from datastore database

Comment: To put data into datastore you need datapusher.

Comment: Hi again, I'm trying to insert data to datastore with api. ( curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/3/action/datastore_create -H "Authorization: {YOUR-API-KEY}" -d '{"resource_id": "{RESOURCE-ID}", "fields": [ {"id": "a"}, {"id": "b"} ], "records": [ { "a": 1, "b": "xyz"}, {"a": 2, "b": "zzz"} ]}'


)     I use  my API-KEY but what is the RESOURCE-ID?  I refer this guide  : http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.2.3/datastore.html#datapusher-automatically-add-data-to-the-datastore

Comment: I set datastore and datapusher and  I try to use 'upload to datastore' menu in ckan web. I got this error.       ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='default.my.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/3/action/resource_show (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)

Comment: You asked "what is purpose of default_datastore database in ckan?". If that is answered, please accept it. Create new questions for these separate requests.

Comment: Ok Thanks D Read!